# How to convert rails request.env to javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have next js.erb file:

```
<% if Rails.env == 'production' %>
  <% if request.env['SERVER_NAME'] == 'example.com' %>
    $(function () {
     ...
     ...
    });
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How to convert second line in JavaScript without Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer as:

```
<% if Rails.env == 'production' %>
 if (window.location.hostname == 'example.com') {
   $(function () {
   ...
   ...
   });
  }
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Output the `SERVER_NAME` as a string, and do the comparison client-side:

```
<% if Rails.env == 'production' %>
  if ('<%= request.env['SERVER_NAME'] %>' == 'example.com') {
    $(function () {
     ...
     ...
    });
  }
<% end %>
```

If the second line can "only contain javascript" (I strongly question this) then you can move the Ruby bit out to a variable:

```
var serverName = '<%= request.env['SERVER_NAME'] %>';

<% if Rails.env == 'production' %>
  if (serverName == 'example.com') {
    $(function () {
     ...
     ...
    });
  }
<% end %>
```

Comment: It is necessary that the second line contained only javascript, in my case.

Comment: @MicRum That's extremely arbitrary. If it can only contain JavaScript, than move the Ruby stuff out to a variable. See update.

Comment: My js.erb file is included in the application.js, so when compiling assets on server undesirable apply to the request.env